# Group by SQL (or if value is on another table)

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table of tournament results with points earned. I want to publish SUM of points for each player and ORDER BY SUM of points DESC.

To do this I need to get all results and then group by LVID. The problem is that players LVID is on table A or table B.

This is how my code looks right now:

```
SELECT p1.id, p2.id, SUM(tr.points)
                FROM tournament_results tr
                JOIN entries e ON tr.e_id = e.al_id
                JOIN tournaments t ON tr.tournament_id = t.id
                LEFT JOIN players_lv p1 ON e.player1_lvid = p1.id
                LEFT JOIN players_lv p2 ON e.player2_lvid = p2.id
                WHERE t.date_added < '2018-01-01' AND player1_lvid IS NOT NULL AND t.date < '2018-01-01'
                GROUP BY p1.id
```

For now, I just group by p1.id. But actually, I need to order where player1_lvid = ... OR player2_lvid. But the final result should be not just a single row, but for all players. (to show ranking eventually)

Comment: Take a look at IFNULL function in mysql.

Comment: Doesn't `AND player1_lvid IS NOT NULL` ensure that player1 id is always there?

Comment: Please include sample data, table definitions and expected output in your question